# Do these algorithms to construct the graphs with a particular property have any importance?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I found a semi-general solution to the following open-ended question and obtained the explicit algorithms to construct the graphs with the following special property. But does my solution have any importance?

[image]

Comment: If no solution currently exists, and yours provably works, I'd say of course it's interesting.  But you might want to ask the research experts at mathoverflow.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will try to ask them.